# clock display same time on different time zone javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timezone, clock

I want to display multiple clock base on different time zone

I'm using [analogClockJs](https://github.com/kenlam0083/analogClockJs) -  a standalone JavaScript library to generate customizable, easy-to-style Analog Clocks using plain JavaScript & CSS.

[javascript clock demo](https://www.cssscript.com/create-customizable-analog-clocks-using-pure-js-analogclockjs/)

```js
function AnalogClock(id, option, datestr) {

  var dateTimeFormat = function(time) {
    var str = "";
    str += time.getYear() + (time.getYear() > 1900 ? 0 : 1900) + "-";
    str += time.getMonth() + 1 + "-";
    str += time.getDate() + "<br/> ";
    str += time.getHours() + ":";
    str += time.getMinutes() + ":";
    str += time.getSeconds();
    return str;
  }

  if (!option)
    option = {}; //avoid undefined exception
  this.foreColor = option.foreColor ? option.foreColor : "#000"; //text color
  this.bgColor = option.bgColor ? option.bgColor : "#eee";
  this.width = option.width ? option.width : 400;

  this.container = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!this.container)
    return;
  this.container.style.fontcolor = this.foreColor;

  //the static part

  //the outer panel of the clock, including the background
  this.panel = document.createElement("div"); //border-radius:50%;background-color:#eee;border:solid 1px #ccc;width:400px;height:400px;position:relative;
  this.panel.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  this.panel.style.backgroundColor = this.bgColor;
  this.panel.style.border = "solid 1px #ccc";
  this.panel.style.width = this.width + "px";
  this.panel.style.height = this.width + "px";
  this.panel.style.position = "relative";
  this.container.appendChild(this.panel);

  //the digital clock on the panel
  var label = document.createElement("h4"); //width:80%;line-height:40px;text-align:center;margin-top:250px;color:#333;

  label.style.width = "100%";
  label.style.textAlign = "center";
  label.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  label.style.fontSize = this.width / 10 + "px";
  label.style.marginTop = this.width * 0.6 + "px";
  label.style.color = this.foreColor;
  label.innerHTML = dateTimeFormat(datestr);
  if (this.width >= 100) //hide if the width is not enough to show the digital clock
    this.panel.appendChild(label);

  //the container of hour numbers on the panel
  var ul = document.createElement("ul"); //padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;left:180px;            
  ul.style.height = "100%";

  ul.style.padding = "0";
  ul.style.margin = "0";
  ul.style.listStyle = "none";
  ul.style.position = "absolute";
  ul.style.width = 40 + "px";
  ul.style.top = 0;
  ul.style.left = this.width / 2 - 20 + "px";
  ul.style.color = this.foreColor;
  this.panel.appendChild(ul);

  //the list of hour numbers on the panel
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (!localStorage) //if html5 not supported
      break;

    var list = document.createElement("li"); //padding:0;margin:0; position: absolute; text-align:center;width:40px;height:400px;font-size:40px; 
    list.style.padding = "0";
    list.style.margin = "0";
    list.style.position = "absolute";
    list.style.textAlign = "center";
    list.style.width = "40px";
    list.style.height = this.width + "px";
    list.style.fontSize = this.width / 10 + "px";
    ul.appendChild(list);

    list.style.transform = "rotate(" + 360 / 12 * (i + 1) + "deg)";

    //a pair of numbers, such as  1 and 7, 3 and 9, etc.
    var numTop = document.createElement("div"); //width:100%;position:absolute;text-align:center;
    numTop.style.width = "100%";
    numTop.style.position = "absolute";
    numTop.style.textAlign = "center";
    numTop.innerHTML = i + 1;
    if (this.width < 100)
      numTop.innerHTML = "�?";
    list.appendChild(numTop);

    numTop.style.transform = "rotate(" + -360 / 12 * (i + 1) + "deg)"; //recover the rotation

    var numBottom = document.createElement("div"); //width:100%;position:absolute;text-align:center;
    numBottom.style.width = "100%";
    numBottom.style.position = "absolute";
    numBottom.style.textAlign = "center";
    numBottom.style.bottom = "0";
    numBottom.innerHTML = i + 7;
    if (this.width < 100)
      numBottom.innerHTML = "�?";
    list.appendChild(numBottom);

    numBottom.style.transform = "rotate(" + -360 / 12 * (i + 1) + "deg)"; //recover the rotation
  }

  //hour hand
  var hour = document.createElement("div"); //width:8px;height:8px;left:196px;top:96px;border-top:solid 100px #ff6a00; border-bottom-width:100px;  
  var hourWidth = this.width * 0.02;
  var hourTop = this.width * 0.25 - (hourWidth * 0.5);
  var hourleft = this.width * 0.5 - hourWidth * 0.5;
  hour.style.width = hourWidth + "px";
  hour.style.height = hourWidth + "px";
  hour.style.position = "absolute";
  hour.style.border = "solid 0px transparent";
  hour.style.left = hourleft + "px";
  hour.style.top = hourTop + "px";
  hour.style.borderTop = "solid " + (this.width * 0.5 - hourTop) + "px #f60";
  hour.style.borderBottomWidth = (this.width * 0.5 - hourTop) + "px";
  if (localStorage) //only visible in HTML5 supported browser
    this.panel.appendChild(hour);

  //minute hand
  var min = document.createElement("div"); //width:4px;height:4px;left:198px;top:48px;border-top:solid 150px #0094ff; border-bottom-width:150px;  
  var minWidth = this.width * 0.01;
  var minTop = this.width * 0.1 - (minWidth * 0.5);
  var minleft = this.width * 0.5 - minWidth * 0.5;
  min.style.width = minWidth + "px";
  min.style.height = minWidth + "px";
  min.style.position = "absolute";
  min.style.border = "solid 0px transparent";
  min.style.left = minleft + "px";
  min.style.top = minTop + "px";
  min.style.borderTop = "solid " + (this.width * 0.5 - minTop) + "px #09f";
  min.style.borderBottomWidth = (this.width * 0.5 - minTop) + "px";
  if (localStorage)
    this.panel.appendChild(min);

  //second hand
  var sec = document.createElement("div"); //width:1px;height:1px;position:absolute;border:solid 0px transparent;left:199px;top:19px;border-top:solid 180px #333; border-bottom-width:180px;  
  var secWidth = 1;
  var secTop = this.width * 0.05;
  sec.style.width = secWidth + "px";
  sec.style.height = secWidth + "px";
  sec.style.position = "absolute";
  sec.style.border = "solid 0px transparent";
  sec.style.left = (this.width * 0.5 - secWidth) + "px";
  sec.style.top = secTop + "px";
  sec.style.borderTop = "solid " + (this.width * 0.5 - secTop) + "px " + this.foreColor;
  sec.style.borderBottomWidth = (this.width * 0.5 - secTop) + "px";
  if (localStorage)
    this.panel.appendChild(sec);

  //the center point
  var point = document.createElement("div"); //content:"";background-color:#333;width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;left:195px;top:195px;border-radius:50%; 
  var pointWidth = this.width * 0.05;
  point.style.width = pointWidth + "px";
  point.style.height = pointWidth + "px";
  point.style.position = "absolute";
  point.style.backgroundColor = this.foreColor;
  point.style.left = this.width * 0.5 - (pointWidth * 0.5) + "px";
  point.style.top = this.width * 0.5 - (pointWidth * 0.5) + "px";
  point.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  if (localStorage)
    this.panel.appendChild(point);
  //start the clock (the animation part)

  this.loop = setInterval(function() {
    const clocks = document.getElementsByClassName("clock1");
    for (let clock of clocks) {
      let timezone = clock.dataset.timezone;
      var targetTime = new Date();
      var tzDifference = parseInt(timezone) * 60 + targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
      var now = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
      label.innerHTML = dateTimeFormat(now);
      var roS = 1.0 * 360 / 60 * now.getSeconds();
      var roM = 1.0 * 360 / 60 * now.getMinutes();
      var roH = 1.0 * 360 / 12 * (now.getHours() % 12) + 1.0 * 360 / 12 * (now.getMinutes() / 60);
      sec.style.transform = 'rotate(' + roS + 'deg)';
      min.style.transform = 'rotate(' + roM + 'deg)';
      hour.style.transform = 'rotate(' + roH + 'deg)';

    }
  });
}
```

call clock function

```js
window.onload = analog();

function analog() {
  const clocks = document.getElementsByClassName("clock1");
  var d = 0;
  for (let clock of clocks) {
    let timezone = clock.dataset.timezone;
    var targetTime = new Date();
    var tzDifference = parseInt(timezone) * 60 + targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
    var date = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
    AnalogClock('clock' + d, {
      width: 140,
      bgColor: "#fff"
    }, date);
    d++;
  }
}
```

clock html code

```php
<?php 
  $clock = 0;
  foreach( $cities as $city) {
    $checktime = isValidTimezoneId(@$city['timezone']);
    if ($checktime==1) {
      $zoneoffset = new DateTime(@$city['timezone']); 
?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style=" border-bottom: 5px solid #eee; padding-top: 2%;">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h2 class="heading">

      <img alt="<?php echo $city['country_name'];?>" style=" margin-bottom: -5px;" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/flags/24x24/'.strtolower($city['country_code']).'.png')?>">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url('time/'.$city['country_slug'].'/'.$city['city_slug']);?>">
        <?php echo  $city['city_name']?>
      </a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <p>
      <span class="clock1" id="clock<?php echo $clock;?>" data-timezone="<?php echo $zoneoffset->format('P');?>"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php   
      $clock++;
    }
  }
?>
```

on this img show same time on different time zone 
 [image: check clock time here]

when page load it show different time and date base on time zones when javascript clock code run in intreval then display same time on all clock

Comment: Well, you can't, unless you will modify the library code. Because the library is using `new Date()` - which means, now, according local zone, in the `setInterval` method. [here](https://github.com/kenlam0083/analogClockJs/blob/master/analogClock.js#L181)

Comment: you mean its not work on daynimc time zones

Comment: Right. it takes by default the time according to the client zone.

Comment: no actually its not use a local time display time on last time zone  for all clock

Comment: What do you mean by last time zone? Last of what? I'm not sure you are right.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297375/863110

Comment: i have done with different time zones

Comment: http://www.timehubzone.com/time/personal   check here.display different time

Comment: It seems that they are using a [private library](http://www.timehubzone.com/assets/js/personalclock.js) which the clock looks like the analogClock library but the code is different and it does take care about the timezone. But the solution is simple. Just replace the `new Date()` with date with timezone like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439630/863110).

Comment: Hi.  You have not actually asked any *question* in the above.  You just said you wanted to do something and then you pasted a bunch of code.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If instead you were looking for a code review, without any particular question, you should use [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Additionally you should note that you are not using time zones correctly.  Read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the part titled "time zone != offset", and also [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked this library and modify it so you can pass timezone as an option.

https://github.com/moshfeu/analogClockJs

Like this:

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moshfeu/analogClockJs/44405f43471a09fb74f18b15e39e8ca3be7b4166/analogClock.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```

```js
var opt = new AnalogClockOption();
opt.width = 100;
opt.timezone = 2;
var clock = new AnalogClock("clock", opt);
clock.panel.style.border = "solid 1px red";
```

**Working example**

http://jsbin.com/gagitij

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for responding, but unfortunately your change does not reflect the nature of time zones correctly.  Please see my comments on the OP question above.  It also doesn't provide an answer that is useful for future readers.  Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is *not* about providing specific code to individuals, but about providing a valuable set of reusable question and answers that are applicable to a wide variety of situations for future readers.  The question was asked poorly, but also so was your answer.

Comment: thanks for point out actually you are right but I have placed a  link to the city above clock which has all details of timezone