# jonthornton timepicker : How to get hours and minues

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm using the jonthornton/jquery-timepicker and could not find the hours and minutes selected.
All I could find was a string output of the form '10:30pm'.
Can the hours and minutes be accessed directly from the control? 
I imagined you would be able to do this but could not find it. 
The best I've been able to do is what follows, anyone got anything better?

```
$('#StartTime').on('change', function (timeControl) {
    var hoursString;
    if (timeControl.target.value.indexOf("am") >= 0) {
        hoursString = timeControl.target.value.replace("am", ":00 AM");
    }
    else {
        hoursString = timeControl.target.value.replace("pm", ":00 PM");
    }
    var oneDate = new Date(Date.parse("2000-01-01 " + hoursString));
    var minutes = oneDate.getMinutes();
    var hours = oneDate.getHours();

    console.log("Hours : " + hours + " | Minutes : " + minutes);
});
```

Comment: Answering my own question.
Moment seemed a good option...

var date01 = moment("2022-05-27 3:30pm", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mma').toDate();

This takes the format of '3:30pm' that comes from the control and generates a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

The long-standing answer would be Moment.js but it is now considered a [legacy project in maintenance mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) and not recommended for new projects. There are recommendations on their website for replacements, but bringing in a new dependency for this may be overkill.

The value coming in seems to follow a format which we can rely on to make parsing easy.

Format: `H:MMxx`

Key:

- `H` = hour, 1-2 characters
- `MM` = minutes, always 2 characters
- `xx` = am or pm, always 2 characters

```js
var timeArray = timeControl.split(':');
var meridiem = timeArray[1].substring(2, 4);

var hours = parseInt(timeArray[0]) + (meridiem === 'pm' ? 12 : 0);
var minutes = parseInt(timeArray[1].substring(0, 2));
var seconds = 0;

// Local time zone, read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297375/5988852
var date = new Date(); 
date.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds);

// If you want UTC instead
utc =  Date.UTC(
  date.getUTCFullYear(), 
  date.getUTCMonth(), 
  date.getUTCDate(), 
  hours, 
  minutes, 
  seconds
);
var date = new Date(utc);
```