JavaScript get first and last date (yyyy-mm-dd) by month and timezone
I'm trying to get the first and last date of the month, but I get an unexpected result.
This is my code:


var year = 2024;
var month = 9; // October
var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
firstDate = firstDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = firstDay+" | "+firstDate;

var lastDay = new Date(year, month+1, 0);
lastDate = lastDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = lastDay+" | "+lastDate;
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>



I would like to have as result 2024-10-01 and 2024-10-31 as Date() days.
Is this a GMT issue? Should I add hours?
Edit
I don't think this question is the same topic as the suggested duplicate. See the correct answer given by Kaveh Movahedi.

How is this result unexpected? What do you mean by "as Date() days"?

new Date(...) constructs a date in your browser's time zone, but .toISOString() outputs it in the UTC time zone. Use .getFullYear(), .getMonth() and .getDate() instead.

Tue Oct 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 is 2024-09-30 (23:00 GMT +0)

To add to @HeikoTheißen 's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297375/2181514

I've rolled back the last change. Please don't post answers in the question.

How do I format a date in JavaScript?

I see this question as a reopen vote. Could you explain, either in the question update or the comments, how it is different? It is generally the experience of readers here that most duplicate votes are in fact correct, and any minor differences do not reduce the general applicability of the other question.

You can simply use toLocaleString to format the date.
More details in MDN Documentation


var year = 2024;
var month = 9; // October
var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1)
firstDate = firstDay.toLocaleString('en-CA', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
})
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = firstDay+" | "+firstDate

var lastDay = new Date(year, month+1, 0)
lastDate = lastDay.toLocaleString('en-CA', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
   })
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = lastDay+" | "+lastDate
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>



